# "to be gained" or "can be gained"?

Tags: difference

Tell me please if  *to be gained* means the same as *can be gained* in the following sentences.

> Given the giant sets approach is an advanced training method it is best that it not be used by beginners as the compound stress associated with it and the greater potential for injury among those unaccustomed to such stress might offset any benefits **to be gained**/**that can be gained**.

Answer (score 0):

"to be gained" refers to benefits which would be gained if it weren't for the stress.

"can be gained" is the same, except the benefits are not necessarily gained.  Though it is a little verbose like this, so if this is what you wish to convey, I would encourage you to instead say,

> Given the giant sets approach is an advanced training method it is
>   best that it not be used by beginners as the compound stress
>   associated with it and the greater potential for injury among those
>   unaccustomed to such stress might offset any benefits to be
>   **potentially** gained.

Comment: In practice, I find it hard to imagine any contexts where this (somewhat strained) distinction would be significant (especially since ***any*** already establishes a degree of imprecision regarding the benefits). Personally I think both OP's alternatives are primarily just waffle / pompous verbiage, but if it really was important to amplify the "dismissive" implication, that could be done easily and succinctly with plain *...might offset any **potential** benefits.*